# signin cookie disappears before expiring

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, owin

I'm using owin cookie authentication to keep users signed in. But I've noticed that the cookie disappears from the client browser without being expired.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() {
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Startup.CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan),
            IsPersistent = true
        };

        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 100;
        ConfigureCookie(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }

    public static CookieAuthenticationOptions CookieAuthenticationOptions { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureCookie(IAppBuilder app) {
        CookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieName = "TokenHandler"
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationOptions);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any clue? I'm not hundred procent sure of this, but thats the feeling I've get because I need to signin a lot more now..Is it possible that a new release of the website could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are sure that the cookie is created correctly (you can see it on the browser profiler and the expiration date is the correct one), and you are also sure that you can navigate the website without a problem.....

Tests: check if you only loose the cookie AFTER closing the browser... if that is the case probably the cause if the browser settings it self. Some settings allow to NOT store then from "session" to "session".